# React how to apply more than one filter before mapping over array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, filter

on Selection option the state is supposed to change and re-render the page with the filtered data,
currently,
the code is able to filter the origin param correctly, but it's unable to keep the filtered origin when applying another filter likle the destintation,

```
const [Flight, setFlights] = useState([]);
  const [OriginCountry, setOrigin] = useState([]);
  const [Airline, setAirline] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");


  const [origin, setORG] = useState("");
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState('');


const useFlights = Flight.filter((flights) => {
    return  origin.length > -1
    ? flights
    : origin === flights.Origin_country_id &&
    destination.length === 0
      ?  flights
      : destination === flights.Destination_country_id
 
    

      // flights.Origin_country_id === origin || flights.Destination_country_id === destination || flights.Landing_time.toLowerCase().includes(search) 
  }).map((flights) => {
    const originCountry = OriginCountry.find(
      (country) => country.id === flights.Origin_country_id
    );
    const destCountry = OriginCountry.find(
      (country) => country.id === flights.Destination_country_id
    );
    const airlineCompany = Airline.find(
      (country) => country.id === flights.Airline_company_id
    );

<div class="form-group">
        <Select
          id="from"
          type="text"
          placeholder="from"
          name="from"
          options={options}
          onChange={(e) => setORG(e.value)}
          
          
        />
        <Select
          id="DE"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Destination"
          name="destination"
          options={options}
          onChange={(e) => setDestination(e.value)}
         
        />
```

how do i make it work so both filters can apply and filter the data correctly and if there's no matches to display a message?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I am not able to see the use of `useState`, but as a suggestion you can do something like this

```
  const [origins, setOrigins] = useState(originsData);
  const [filteredOrigins, setFilteredOrigins] = useState(originsData);
```

NOTE : in your logic after applying filter just update `filteredOrigins` using `setFilteredOrigins(result)`

Comment: currently it sets the state of origin and filter to what matches the data, and then maps over it,
could you tell me more about your suggested solution

Comment: @Chickin add one more state for filtered records. initially make it equal to original state. but on subsequent filters modify filtered origins to keep already applied filters

Answer (score 0):

- per React naming conventions, you should only ever prefix a variable with `use` if its a hook. You most likely are getting a warning with the naming there.
- `useFlights` is a perfect memoization candidate. Since it depends on the state of two other state variables, you could optimize `useFlights` to only recompute when the depending variables change by wrapping it with a useMemo. Example:

```
const useFlights = useMemo(()=>{
return Flight.filter((flights) => {
    ...
  }).map((flights) => {
    ...
  })
},[origin, destination])
```

- Lastly, I'm pretty sure your issue is the optional chaining bit in the filter function. It's pretty confusing what's going on there and it may not be working as you'd expect. I'd change it up to be clearer, maybe something like this:

```
if(origin.length > -1 || destination.length === 0){
  return flights 
}
return origin === flights.Origin_country_id || destination === flights.Destination_country_id
```

Hope this helps.